# (iOS, ShareKit) Is there any way of determining whether or not a user is logged in to Twitter?

Tags: twitter, oauth, sharekit

I am using ShareKit to add a "share to Twitter" button to my app.  However I also need to show a "log out" button to allow the user to log out of his/her Twitter account.  But I only want the button to show up if the user is actually logged in.  Is there any way of determining whether a user has given Twitter credentials to ShareKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call

```
[SHKTwitter isServiceAuthorized]
```

This will return a BOOL indicating if the user has already authenticated against Twitter. As an aside, this also works against any class that subclasses SHKSharer.